# Когда стирается TEMPRORARY TABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Работаю с `MariaDB 10.6`. Создал хранимую процедуру, а рамках которой создавалась временная таблица:

```
CREATE
    DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE my_procedure()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS (SELECT id FROM some_table);

    # some logic

    COMMIT;
END;
```

У меня создалось впечатление, что эта таблица не стирается сразу по завершении процедуры, потому что у меня были некоторые проблемы с её использованием. После того, как я сделал удаление таблицы перед её созданием, все ошибки ушли:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_temp_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table AS (SELECT id FROM some_table);
```

Вопрос следующий: когда именно стирается `TEMPORARY TABLE`, если мы создаём её в рамках процедуры?

На сайте `MariaDB` написано следующее:

> Use the TEMPORARY keyword to create a temporary table that is only
> available to the current session. Temporary tables are dropped when
> the session ends. Temporary table names are specific to the session.

Но разве по завершении процедуры сессия не должна закрываться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но разве по завершении процедуры сессия не должна закрываться?

Cессия с точки зрения клиента - это соединение с БД, и для её закрытия нужен `Connection.Close`.

Если ты после выполнения процедуры не закрываешь соединение и держишь его, то сессия открыта, и таблица висит и никуда не девается.

Другое дело если соединение явно закрывается. Ну или сессия может быть закрыта сервером - по тайм-ауту, скажем, если клиент завис, или если соединение кильнули. Вот тогда и таблица вместе с соединением уходит в небытие.

Кстати, тут бывает и медвежья услуга. Соединение можно настроить на автопереподключение при обрыве - но после переподключения темптаблицы уже не будет...